# Why $\Omega(E) \propto E^N$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In statistical mechanics class , it is assumed $\Omega(E) \propto E^N$ where $\Omega(E)$ is the no of microstates corresponding to energy E in a system where no of particles is constant and total energy of reservoir and system is constant. The system is in contact with a reservoir and N is the total no of particles in the system. Why is it assumed like that

Comment: Don't ask the same question again after deleting the very same before. Instead, edit the previous one and if it was closed, try to re-open.

Comment: I did edit.. but its still closed

Comment: Still, you shouldn't ask the same question again. Try to edit further, and perhaps ask for help in comments or so

Comment: Can you give a bit more context of your system? For an ideal gas I get $\Omega \sim E^{\frac{(D\cdot N) - 1}{2}}$, which differs from your expression. Where D is the dimensionality of your 1 particle position space.

Comment: A couple of simple examples should convince you that it is false. However, in the thermodynamic limit, you expect the scaling $$\Omega = e^{Ns(E/N)}$$ with $s$ having a well defined limit as a function. This is motivated by extensivity, and you recognise it as  entropy. In general, $s$ is not just a logarithm but a complicated function of $E/N$.